# Display atributes value and name in cart woocomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Simple question how to display product atributes in cart woocomerce: for example color:red, not sure if there is some code to add like hook or some code to fundctions.php or it can be done through woocomerce settings, have not found any useful information online, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do a simple things as follows, you will get all in your cart_item -

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'add_variations_in_cart', 10, 3);
function add_variations_in_cart($name, $cart_item, $item_key){
    $product_variation = '';
    if(!empty($cart_item['variation_id']) && $cart_item['variation_id'] != 0 ){
       if(is_array($cart_item['variation']) && !empty($cart_item['variation'])){
          foreach ($cart_item['variation'] as $key => $value) {
             $product_variation .= '<br>'.ucfirst(str_replace('attribute_pa_', '', $key)).' : '.ucfirst($value);
        }
    }
}

echo $name.$product_variation;
```

}

as simple as that. Thank you.

Comment: you can pass your html structure in $product_variation as you want. As per you something like $product_variation .= '<br><span class="attr_lbl">'.ucfirst(str_replace('attribute_pa_', '', $key)).' :</span><span class="attr_val"> '.ucfirst($value).'</span>';

Answer (score 0):

tyr this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-show-attributes/

OR

WooCommerce: show all product attributes listed below each item on Cart page

add this below code in function.php

```
/**
    * WooCommerce: show all product attributes listed below each item on Cart page
    */
    function sm_woo_cart_attributes($cart_item, $cart_item_key){

        $item_data = $cart_item_key['data'];
        $attributes = $item_data->get_attributes();


        if ( ! $attributes ) {
            return $cart_item;
        }

        $out = $cart_item . '<br />';

        foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {

            if ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] ) {

            // skip variations
                if ( $attribute['is_variation'] ) {
                    continue;
                }

                // backwards compatibility for attributes which are registered as taxonomies

                $product_id = $item_data->id;
                $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $attribute['name'], 'all' );

                // get the taxonomy
                $tax = $terms[0]->taxonomy;

                // get the tax object
                $tax_object = get_taxonomy($tax);

                // get tax label
                if ( isset ($tax_object->labels->name) ) {
                    $tax_label = $tax_object->labels->name;
                } elseif ( isset( $tax_object->label ) ) {
                    $tax_label = $tax_object->label;
                }

                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $out .= $tax_label . ': ';
                    $out .= $term->name . '<br />';
                }

            } else {

                // not a taxonomy 

                $out .= $attribute['name'] . ': ';
                $out .= $attribute['value'] . '<br />';
            }
        }
        echo $out;
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sm_woo_cart_attributes, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-show-attributes/